# Group elements in a cell in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell size of 1x142884 (I have 142884 elements in a single cell) and I am interested to group these elements in a cell of 36 each. So I must have `142884 / 36 = 3969` cells. Can someone help me to group those cells where each cell consist of 36 cells. 
**EDIT**
Here is my code

```
yaml_file = 'Feature000000';
YamlStruct = ReadYaml(yaml_file);
feature0 =  YamlStruct.features1;
blocks_per_img = YamlStruct.blockperimg;
```

You can download Feature000000 file from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/95yrfwee84dgh3m/Feature000000?dl=0)

Comment: Use [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) on the matrix inside your single cell. Give it a try and report back if you get stuck...

Comment: Do you mean by ‘a single cell’ a cell of size 1×1, and that single cell contains something of size 1×142884?

Comment: I have a single cell and it's size is 1x142884. @Erik

Comment: I am trying to understand how `mat2cell` works @Dan

Comment: `mat2cell(C{1}, 36*ones(3969,1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [reshape](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) as follows:

```
B = reshape(C,36,3969)
```

You'll end up with a cell `B` of size 36×3969, so every row is one of the 36 items with length 3969.

Comment: it does create 36x3969 cell. Can you please let me how to access first 36 values. I have updated my question with the code and file. With this approach I have wrong values. @Erik

Comment: The first 36 values would be the first column then, i.e. `B{:,1}`.

Comment: I believe this technique won't work as I need 36 consecutive elements. from 1 x 142884. Can you please check ? @Erik

Comment: You can use `B = reshape(C,3969,36)` as well, then every row in `B` is one of the 3969 groups containing 36 elements. Access row `n` with `B{n,:}`.

Comment: No, I believe u misunderstood the question I need 36 consecutive elements from 142884 to form a cell and I will have 3969 cells. Please check my uploaded file. @Erik